# Changing wordpress custom field into hyperlink

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

In my WordPress site I have created a custom field for author website link, but I don't know how to make it hyperlink. People must be able to click on it to surf that website.

At this moment it only shows raw text, like: "www.example.com"

My code is:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Author Website', true); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid broken HTML, you need to first check if the link exists and then display it.

To do that, you need to use an if statement:

```
if( $link = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Author Website', true ) )
```

As for the link itself, a regular HTML anchor tag looks like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/">http://www.example.com/</a>
```

For the example, I'm using the sprintf function, which will replace %s with the proper value:

```
if( $link = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Author Website', true ) ) {
    sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>',
        esc_attr( $link ),
        $link
    );
}
```

In this example I'm using esc_attr() to make sure that the link will not break the page layout.

Hope this works for you :)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I already modified my code, which working perfectly right now. here it is:
`<a href="http://<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Author Website', true); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Author Website', true); ?></a>`

so what do you suggest, should I try your method or the present one is just fine?

Comment: The current one should be sufficient as long as there is an 'Author Website' set. If there is not site, the link will appear, but it will not work and might disappoint someone.

Theoretically, you only need to replace the code, so I suggest that you should give it a try :)